Peak search for NLS equation solutions
By solving the initial value problem of the NLS equation, I can get a matrix of numerical solutions. I hope to perform a peak search on the matrix of this numerical solution, that is, there are multiple peaks in the resulting matrix, and I need to identify the positions and heights of these peaks.
The important thing is that there may be some wavelets caused by noise, and how to identify the real wave peaks.
Is there any corresponding numerical algorithm?

It seems you only need a filter to smooth out the noises. The wave peaks should be where the gradient vanishes and Hessian is sufficiently negative.
